# Getting message contiously on telegram

Tags: python, flask, telegram-bot

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,jsonify
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

url = ''
token = ''

def send_message(chat_id,text):
    URL = url+token+'sendMessage'
    answer = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}
    r = requests.post(URL,json = answer)
    return ''


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        chat_id = r['message']['chat']['id']
        text = "how are you?"
        send_message(chat_id,text)
    else:
        return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

when I run this after setting the webhook I keep getting the text 'how are you?' continuously. How do i fix this? I saw 2 answers telling to return 200 Ok. Could anyone please help ?

Comment: What do you return from your `index` method for that POST request? Cueck with `curl` if necessary.

Comment: I return the text 'how are you?'

Comment: I mean the whole thing, like what response code? Are you sending back the right headers? Maybe Telegram thinks you didn't process it so it retries aggressively. I'd check the specification to make sure you're sending back all the things you should be.

Comment: I mean your HTTP response, the whole thing, including headers. Do you know what you're supposed to send back? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem here. Is this `index` method being fired multiple times? Is Telegram being hit multiple times with `send_message`?

Comment: I think a 200 Ok response . That's what I got from this (https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot/issues/159)

Comment: Adding a return 'OK' statement after post request solved the problem

Comment: If you've got a concrete solution it's worth adding a self-answer.

Comment: It worked but I don't know why. Shouldn't the response be sent to the telegram server?

Comment: If you don't acknowledge the request properly, it likely gets retried.